# Controlling the port of /webservices/Configuration/ReadService.svc

Tags: configuration, 2013

I have a simple console app which has the following line of code:

```
Session session = new Session(username);
```

It always throws the following error

```
{"Unable to connect to service. Please see inner exception for details: There was 
no endpoint listening at `http://localhost:81/webservices/Configuration/ReadService.svc`
that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or 
SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."}
```

It seems like I have a config file somewhere pointing at port 81 on my server. Where is this configured? When I access `http://localhost/webservices/Configuration/ReadService.svc` on my machine I can see the web service.

I tried searching my machine for references to localhost:81, but that didn't seem to reveal the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a setting in the registry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\TRIDION_CONFIGURATION_URL` which contains the ReadService, could that perhaps be set incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks Bart - That is exactly what I was after. Changing that value, and restarting the server seemed to do the trick. Do you happen to know when that value is used? My system seemed to be working normally except for when I write that line of code.

Comment: @Chris, I don't really know, must be something internal as it appears to be related to the `new Session()` call indeed

Answer (score 4):

I am pretty sure this is on the System.config, but unfortunately can't verify it now. I can however tell you why it is on Port 81.

The installer was probably executed on a brand new server, which did not have the IIS role installed. This means the installer added the role, which comes with a site on port 80 (the IIS default site) and it will show an error message stating that "Cannot use port 80, do you want to use port 81 instead"?

I tend to always install the IIS role before running the installer to avoid this situation.

I'll try to check which file it's on once I get an instance running around here.

Comment: No sign of it in the system.config stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\web\WebUI\WebRoot\Configuration

Answer (score 1):

Was your CMS implementation installed under :81 but you've since changed it?

I would search the Tridion_Home folder and its subfolders for "81" otherwise, search your 'client' folders for 81.

UPDATE:

Perhaps you could share some more code and the service snippets from your web.config?

Comment: I am not sure (possibly) - and trust me - I searched before posting this...

Comment: Which web.config - this is a console app? Nothing binding specific in my app.config